# getting error of 'Missing $ inserted' and 'Extra }, or forgotten $.' and 'Missing } inserted.' while running a table in overleaf latex

Tags: latex, overleaf

I am writting a table on latex overleaf system ,and got such error message for such a table

```
\begin{table}[h]
\caption{The first scenario: supervised learning versus normal self-supervised learning approach for learning features for a pose estimation downstream task. There is no intermediate stage in this approach.}\label{tab2}
\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|l|}
\hline
Model & Datasets &Status &AP &AP^{50} & AP^{75}&AP^{M}  &AP^{L}& AR& AR^{50}& AR^{75}& AR^{M} &AR^{L}&Epochs\\
\hline
\multirow{2}{*}{ResNet-50}&ACID$_p$& Sup & \textbf{0.4455}&\textbf{1.0} & \textbf{0.3307}&  -1.0& \textbf{0.4455}&\textbf{0.4867} &\textbf{1.0}& \textbf{0.4667}&   -1.0&\textbf{0.4867}& 120\\
&ImageNet& Self-Sup &0.37962 & 0.80528& 0.17327&    -1.0& 0.37962&0.42  &0.86667& 0.2&  -1.0&0.42 & 590\\
\hline
\multirow{2}{*}{HRNet-W32}&ACID$_p$ & Sup& \textbf{0.4228} & \textbf{1.0}& \textbf{0.3187}& -1.0&  \textbf{0.4228}&\textbf{0.520} &\textbf{1.0}& \textbf{0.5333}&   -1.0& \textbf{0.520}& 120\\ 
&ImageNet & Self-Sup& 0.3832 & 0.7958& 0.2911&-1.0&0.3832 &0.4200 &0.8667&0.3333 &-1.0  & 0.4200& 450\\ 
\hline
\end{tabular}

}
\end{table}
```

any idea to help me understand the source of error and how to solve it ?
i am thinking that the error comes from the subscript of AR°{50}

i am trying to remove ^ with something else but it does not work

Comment: Please post the error message as well.

Answer (score 0):

The character `^` should only be used for superscripts in mathematical expressions so you need to enclose each of your superscripts in `$`.

From this : `AP^{50}`

To this: `AP$^{50}$`